# Invalid usage of this.props in react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the following error on webpack build and I don't understand why:

```
SyntaxError: this is a reserved word (11:5)
```

It occurs inside the `Applicatons` class at the code which says `this.props.apps.map`. Its trying to iterate through the passed apps property and create a JSX representation of `Application` components. I've included the Applications class as the first piece of code and the subsequent code shows how I instantiate the Applications component in a different class. **I'm trying to access the props field inside the Applications class which extends the React Component**

Here is the Applications class which I am clearly not using React props correctly:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Application from './Application/Application';
import ErrorBoundary from '../ErrorBoundary/ErrorBoundary';

class Applications extends React.Component {

       render(){           
          let applicationsList=null;
          applicationsList = (
             {this.props.apps.map((app,index)=>{
               return <Application 
                  name={app.name} 
                  desc={app.desc}
                  changed={(event)=>this.props.changed(event,app.id)}
                  click={()=>this.props.clicked(index)}
                  key={app.id}
                />
          })}
       );
       return (
        {applicationsList}
       )
    }
}
```

And here is the code inside a different react component that instantiates the Applications component.

```
render(){
  let applications=null;
  applications = (
    <div>
     <Applications 
            apps={this.state.apps} 
            clicked={this.deleteApplicationHandler}
            changed={this.nameChangedHandler}/>
    </div>
  );
  return (<div>{applications}</div>);
}
```

I'm extremely new to react so i apologize if i missed anything if i did please let me know and ill update the question.

Comment: There's no guarantee that Applications has the props before render.  You might want to conditionally render if this.props.apps.

And/or include 
`constructor(props) {
 super(props)
}`
to the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use JSX templating syntax outside JSX. Curly brackets are interpreted as defining an object literal. Remove the extra brackets.

```
render(){           
  let applicationsList=null;
  applicationsList = this.props.apps.map((app,index)=>{
    return <Application 
      name={app.name} 
      desc={app.desc}
      changed={(event)=>this.props.changed(event,app.id)}
      click={()=>this.props.clicked(index)}
      key={app.id}
    />
   });

   return applicationsList;
}
```

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. for render method of Applications isnt render method supposed to return JSX maybe i shoukldnt be using render?

Comment: Are you still trying to return `({applicationsList})`? That isn't JSX. If it doesn't have HTML/XML tags then it's not JSX. Either return only the list like in the answer or e.g. `<div>{applicationsList}</div>`.

Comment: Works great. Thanks